# How to create a list of object

Tags: java, android, list, collections, arraylist

Hi I want to know how to create a list of objects. So basically what I am doing is this:

```
ArrayList<Object> FilledTransportList = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

And I want to fill the objects in the list using this method:

```
public boolean checkFields()
{
    for (Map.Entry<String, EditText> entry : checkMap.entrySet()) 
    {
        String checkData = entry.getKey();
        String text = entry.getValue().getText().toString();

        if(text.length()>0)
        {
           FilledTransportList.add(checkData + " - " + text +" - " + "min");      
        }

    }

    return true;
}
```

But whit this what I get is a list of strings.

```
[something, something, something...etc]
```

I want it to be like this:

```
[something],[something],[something],[something]...etc
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why don't you split them and get it in that format?

Comment: what do you mean can you show me with an example?

Comment: String extends Object. The code behaviour is the expected. What do you really want?

Comment: Does your [something,something...] means [checkData + " - " + text +" - " + "min", checkData + " - " + text +" - " + "min", checkData + " - " + text +" - " + "min"...]?

Comment: yes it does mean checkData + " - " + text +" - " + "min"

Comment: and I want the list FilledTransportList to be filled with objects not with strings

that is why I made: [something],[something],[something],[something]...etc

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to understand what you mean to do, but I know why you are getting a list of strings. You are adding strings to the list with this line:

```
FilledTransportList.add(checkData + " - " + text +" - " + "min");
```

If you are trying to make a list of user defined objects, then when you create your ArrayList, you should have the name of the user defined object between the '<>' and not "Object". By using the superclass Object, you can place an object of any type in the list, which is why you are able to add strings to the list. String is a subclass of Object.

Comment: Hmm may be I did not explain what I want very clearly so I will try again. I want each new entry in the "FilledTransportList" to be a separated object from the rest of the entries

Comment: @user3182266: they ARE separate objects, that are strings in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an statement like this:

```
System.out.println (FilledTransportList)
```

When you are doing this, the toString()-Method from the ArrayList is called.
The toString()-Method implements an Default-Behaviour like this:

[obj1.toString(), obj2.toString(), objN.toString()]

If you want another representation of the list, you have to implement an own method for this.

```
public static String getRepresentation (ArrayList<String> list);
```

and call it like this:

```
System.out.println (getRepresentation (FilledTransportList));
```

Another possibility is to write a class which encapsulates the list and overrides the toString()-Method.

Comment: Wait I got really confused ... and I messed up big time I want to create a list of objects. That means that I want to see when I hover over the list "FilledTransportList" 2 arrays of objects. One containing the data from "checkData" and 2 containing the "text"

Answer (score 0):

It won't work that way for any known datatypes. Its not only the case with String, but it happens the same way with Integer, BigDecimal etc.

Now if you are looking for data abstraction its better to have a temporary object with a String and its getter and setter.

```
public class TestObject {
   private String abc;
}
```

Now add to the list:

```
TestObject obj = new TestObject(); 
obj.setAbc(checkData + " - " + text +" - " + "min");
FilledTransportList.add(obj);
```